# Calling another Script from Command Line in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am having problem in understanding the following line of code ..

```
/home/rmsbatch/autoscript/autorms.ksh dc_load_main.ksh -q belk_dc_load_tran_data.seq
```

What's being done here ? what does "-q" means ? What does ".seq" file means in unix "belk_dc_load_tran_data.seq"

Please elaborate

autorms.ksh

---

```
#!/bin/ksh
################################################################################
# Description : Execute RMS Jobs with Error Reporting
# 
################################################################################
. /home/rmsbatch/.profile
set -x
LOG=/logs/IBM/AutoLogs
CMNLOG=$LOG/BatchStatus_`date +"%y%m%d`.txt

if [ "${1}" == "prepost" ] || [ "${1}" == "bprepost" ]
then
        exec > ${LOG}/Auto_${1}_${3}.log 2>&1
else
        exec > ${LOG}/Auto_${1}.log 2>&1
fi



function Error_Log
{
# translate "\n" to "^" below
v1=$(echo -n $1 | tr "\n" "^")
v2=$(echo -n $2 | tr "\n" "^")
echo $(hostname)"|"$(basename $CMD $PARAM3)"|"$(date +%m/%d/%y)"|"$(date +%H:%M:%S)"|"$v1"|"$v2 |grep "Failed"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
echo $(hostname)"|"$(basename $CMD $PARAM3)"|"$(date +%m/%d/%y)"|"$(date +%H:%M:%S)"|"$v1"|"$v2 | mail -s "RMS Batch Failed in PROD" rms_app_support@belk.com,bandrest@in.ibm.com,vanarsda@us.ibm.com,wgwinslo@us.ibm.com
fi
echo $(hostname)"|"$(basename $CMD $PARAM3)"|"$(date +%m/%d/%y)"|"$(date +%H:%M:%S)"|"$v1"|"$v2 >> $CMNLOG

}




function RunBatch
{
set -x
                echo "Running the Batch or Script"
                echo "Command" $CMD
                if [[ $check -ne 1 ]]
                then
                        ls $MMBIN/$CMD

                        if [ $? == 0 ] || [ $uRC -eq 0 ]
                        then
                                 echo "------ Running the Command ------"
                                 Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Started"
                 if [ "${CMD}" == "prepost" ] || [ "${CMD}" == "bprepost" ]
                 then
                    ${MMBIN}/${CMD} $PARAM1 $PARAM3 $PARAM4 $PARAM5
                    echo $?| read VResult
                 else
                    cd $MMBIN
                    $SHOME/batch_wrapper.ksh ${CMD} $PARAM1 $PARAM3 $PARAM4 $PARAM5
                    echo $?| read VResult
                 fi 
                 if [ $VResult -eq 0 ]
                 then
                    Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Batch Completed Successfully"
                    VResult=0
                    return $VResult
                 else
                    cat $MMHOME/error/err.${CMD}*.`date +"%b_%d"`|tail -1|grep error    
                    echo $error|read Error
                    echo `$SHOME/batch_wrapper.ksh ${CMD} $PARAM1 $PARAM3 $PARAM4 $PARAM5`|read Error1
                    Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Failed with - $Error Error1"     
                    return $VResult
                 fi


                        else
                                 echo " Command not found in the Directory "
                                 Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Failed for Command Not Found"
                                 VResult=99
                 return $VResult
                        fi
                else
                        echo "------ Running the Command ------"
                        Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Started"
                        $MMHOME/external/scripts/$CMD.ksh $PARAM1 $PARAM3 $PARAM4 $PARAM5 $PARAM6 $PARAM7
                        echo $?|read Result
                        VResult=$Result
                        if [ $VResult -eq 0 ]
            then
                Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3)  Batch Completed Successfully"
                return $VResult
            else
                Error_Log "$(basename $CMD $PARAM3) Failed" 
                return $VResult
            fi
                fi

}


if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
then
        echo $1|grep ksh
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
        then
                CMD=$1
        else
                echo $1|awk -F"." '{print $1}'|read CMD
                check=1
        fi
        LOGIN=$UP
        PARAM1=$2
        PARAM3=$3
        PARAM4=$4
        PARAM5=$5
        PARAM6=$6
        PARAM7=$7

        MMBIN=$MMHOME/oracle/proc/bin
    SHOME=/home/rmsbatch/autoscript
        echo " Shell Started the Command :" ${CMD}
        echo " Parameters Passed are     :" $*
        echo " MM Home Directory         :" $MMHOME


    RunBatch


else
        echo "##############################################################################################################################"
        echo "# Not Enough Parameter Passed Or Usage of Parameter is not Proper"
        echo "# value to be Passed to the Current Shell is : " $#
        echo "# Command being executed is : " $CMD
        echo "# Usage of current command is given below "
        echo ""
        echo "" `$MMHOME/oracle/proc/bin/$1`
        echo "##############################################################################################################################"
        return 99
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`autorms.ksh` is probably a shell script that takes 3 parameters...

the first of which looks to be another script (dc_load_main.ksh) but it is only a guess and not necessarily the case

the second is `-q` which could mean anything

the third is probably another file but you cannot tell what the file should contain as extensions are fairly arbitrary and not enforced in Unix.

In short, you need to read `autorms.ksh` to know anything at all.

Comment: Thanks mark for replying .. I have updated the Question with autorms.ksh code..

Also please let me know what does  exec > ${LOG}/Auto_${1}_${3}.log 2>&1  mean ?